# ReactJS Props are not loaded in componentWillMount() and componentDidMount()

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props, react-select

I have the following code for my React-Select integration and need to set the `selectedOption` field for once before first render.

```
import React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';
 
interface IOption{
    value:string,
    label:string
}

interface Props{
    data : IOption[],
    onSelected : (id:string) => void
}

export default class ReactSelect extends React.Component<Props> {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        console.log("data from constructor : ",this.props.data)
    }

    tempSelectedOption:IOption | undefined
    state = {
        selectedOption:this.tempSelectedOption,
    };  

    componentWillMount(){
        this.setState({ selectedOption : this.props.data[0]},()=>{console.log("component will mount meth:",this.state.selectedOption)})
        console.log("data from componentWillMount : ", this.props.data)
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.setState({ selectedOption : this.props.data[0]},()=>{console.log("component did mount meth:",this.state.selectedOption)})
        console.log("data from componentDidMount : ", this.props.data)
    }

    handleChange = selectedOption => {
        this.setState({ selectedOption });
        this.props.onSelected(selectedOption.value)
        console.log(`Option selected:`, selectedOption);
    };

    render() {
        const{ selectedOption } = this.state;
        console.log("props.data in render :",this.props.data)

        return (
            <Select
                value = {selectedOption}
                onChange = {this.handleChange}
                options = {this.props.data}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

And here some console outputs

```
data from constructor : Array [] 
data from componentWillMount : Array [] 
props.data in render :  Array [] 
data from constructor :   Array [] 
data from componentWillMount : Array [] 
props.data in render :  Array [] 
data from constructor :   Array [] 
data from componentWillMount :   Array [] 
props.data in render : Array [] 
data from componentDidMount : Array [] 
data from componentDidMount : Array [] 
data from componentDidMount : Array [] 
props.data in render :  Array [ {…} ] 
props.data in render :  Array [] 
props.data in render :  Array [ {…} ] 
props.data in render :  Array [ {…} ] 
props.data in render :  Array [ {…} ] 
props.data in render :  Array [ {…} ] 
props.data in render :  Array [ {…} ] 
props.data in render :  Array [ {…} ] 
props.data in render :  Array [ {…}, {…} ] 
props.data in render :  Array [ {…} ]
```

Comment: can you change `constructor(Props)` to `constructor(props)`, its bothering me

Comment: Thank you for your attention, but nothing has changed @Minato

Comment: why would you set the value of a property once a component mounts? That feels like it should be in the state. Or the property should have a default value, if it's not set.

Comment: There's nothing in your component that shows us how `state.selectedOption` is being set, also you have a handler `this.handleChange` that you're now showing. Show us the full component.

Comment: @Iux as you reaquest I load full component. @Julian I wanted that component's default value to be the `data[0]` and I am agree anyway to do that, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I want to thank everyone who paid attention to the question.

As I also commented to @GiovanniEsposito's answer, the situation is pretty much as follows,

In parent component a sdk is involved and the problem is I want to render data[0] as default value but, props.data is loaded after `componentWillMount` `componentDidMount`. Actually the sdk service call is returned even after first render function calling, so when the props.data are updated an additional render method is required. Then `props.data` is become available just in `render` function, so I had to handle the problem in the `render` function.

I modified `render()` as,

```
state = {
    selectedOption:null,
    propsLoaded:false
};  

render() {
    if(this.state.propsLoaded == false && this.props.data[0] != undefined){
        this.setState({ 
            selectedOption : this.props.data[0],
            propsLoaded : true
        })
    }
       
    return (
        <Select
            value = {this.state.selectedOption}
            onChange = {this.handleChange}
            options = {this.props.data}
        />
    );
}
```

As a result I solved my problem but I have a warning which seems not serious for me by now. If I am doing something very wrong please warn me :)

```
Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). 
Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.
```

Answer (score 1):

Ciao, I'm not a typescript lover, but I think your problem could be related on how you pass props to `ReactSelect` component.

I made this (very stupid) [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-qx1mp?file=/src/index.tsx) and props logging seems to work:

In `App` component:

```
...
<Child data={"ciao"} />
...
```

Then the `Child` component:

```
class Child extends React.Component<{}> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log("data from constructor : ",this.props.data)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("data from componentDidMount : ", this.props.data);
  }

  private handleClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    const type: string = event.currentTarget.title;

    this.setState(({ count }) => ({
      count: type === "decrement" ? count - 1 : count + 1
    }));
  };

  public render() {
    console.log("props.data in render :", this.props.data);
    return (
      ...
    );
  }
}
```

And the log shows:

```
data from constructor :  ciao 
props.data in render : ciao 
data from componentDidMount :  ciao
```

Comment: I am sending props from parent component like this `<ReactSelect data= {this.state.workItemDropdownData} onSelected={this.setCurrentWorkItem}/>`

Comment: Ciao, I modified my example passing my `this.state.count` in Child prop but it's working correctly. Could you reproduce your error in codesandbox? Or share a github repo? Just to work with the same code and find a solution faster :)

Comment: here is a situation, in parent component a vss-web-extension sdk is involved (a sdk to help writing azure-devops web extensions). And the problem is I want to render data[0] as default value but, `data` props are passing after `componentWillMount ` `componentDidMount`. Actually the sdk service call is returned even after first render, so when the props are updated an additional render method is required. I hope I make it a little bit clearer :).